# Directional derivative matrix representation

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Consider the definition of the directional derivative of a $C^\infty$ differentiable function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ at the point $x\in\mathbb R^n$ and in the direction $u\in\mathbb R^n$ ($\|u\|_2=1$):

$$
Df(x)(u) := \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+hu)-f(x)}{h}.
$$

$Df(x):\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ is a linear map, thus it admits a matrix representation. **First question**: what is the matrix representation of $Df(x)$ with respect to the standard bases of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ (i.e. $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^m$ respectively)?

Next, consider the second order direction derivative $D^2f(x):\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$, i.e. the "directional derivative of the directional derivative". It too is a linear map, thus it admits a matrix representation. **Second question**: what is the matrix representation of $D^2f(x)$, again with respect to the standard bases?

Note: I am using the "matrix" word loosely. My current thinking leads me to that $D^2f(x)$ is a tensor (like a matrix "box" with a depth dimension as well as rows and columns).

Very importantly, I would like your matrix representations to collapse nicely to the gradient vector for $Df(x)$ and to the Hessian matrix for $D^2f(x)$ in the special case $m=1$.

*Background: this is not homework. I ask this question because we learned about these directional derivatives in class, but I did not manage to understand the above questions. I also could not find a good book which goes through this.*

**Bonus**: a (tensor?) representation for the $k$-th order direction derivative $D^kf(x)$ would be amazing.

Comment: The directional derivative is not necessarily a linear map. If $f$ is differentiable at the point it will be, but that is not necessarily the case. The directional derivative is denoted by something like $df(x,h)$ or similar.

Comment: So I added the extra information that $f$ is smooth.

Comment: The notation $Df(x)$ is used for the derivative. The right hand side of your equation above is the definition of the two sided directional derivative in the direction $u$. There is a disconnect.

Comment: Fixed, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable at $x$ then $df(x,u) = Df(x)u$. $Df(x)$ is the derivative and $[Df(x)]_{ij} = {\partial f_i(x) \over \partial x_j}$.

Comment: Fair, what about the second order derivative? It is the most confusing one for me.

Comment: $D^2f(x)$ is a linear map $\mathbb{R}^n \to ( \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m)$, so it does not have a matrix representation as such. Your question still confuses derivative & directional derivative.

Comment: How come then the Hessian is the matrix representation of $D^2f(x)$ when $m=1$? I also don't understand what you mean by me confusing derivative and directional derivative, other than that our notation may be different.

Comment: $Df(x)$ is the derivative of $f$ at $x$. $df(x,u)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $u$ at $x$.

Comment: The map $\mathbb{R}^n \to ( \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m)$ can be represented as a matrix for $m=1$.

Comment: I think our notations are just different for the directional derivative. Can you please expand on how the case $\mathbb R^n\to(\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R)$ can be expressed as a matrix? What do people represent then $D^2 f(x)$ as for computations?

Comment: I don't want to repeat, but the notation you use is for the derivative not the directional derivative.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier when considering directional derivatives to look at $\phi(t) = f(x+tu)$.

Then $\phi'(t) = \sum_j u_j {\partial f(x+tu) \over \partial x_j}$ and
$\phi''(t) = \sum_i \sum_j u_i u_j {\partial f^2(x+tu) \over \partial x_i x_j}$
and so
$\phi'(0) = \sum_j u_j {\partial f(x) \over \partial x_j}$,
$\phi''(0) = \sum_i \sum_j u_i u_j {\partial f^2(x) \over \partial x_i x_j}$.

It is clear that this process can be continued. In general, the map can be identified as a multilinear map $(\mathbb{R}^n \times \cdots\times \mathbb{R}^n )\to \mathbb{R}^m$ defined by
$(u_1,..., u_k) \to \sum_{i_1} \cdots \sum_{i_k} [u_1]_{i_1} \cdots [u_1]_{i_k} {\partial f^k(x) \over \partial x_{i_1} \cdots  x_{i_k}}$, evaluated at
$(u,...,u)$.

Comment: Your $f$ is mapping to $\mathbb R$, no? Or is this the general $\mathbb R^n$ case?

Comment: This is the general case for $m$ (not $n$).

Comment: Something I noticed: typically there is a different direction one can choose for the second-order directional derivative, e.g. $v$. Am I correct that then you would have $D^2f(x)(u,v)=\frac{d}{dt}\left[\sum_i u_i\frac{\partial f(x+tv)}{\partial x_i}\right]_{t=0}=\sum_{i,j}u_iv_j\frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}$?